# Find nearset neighbours in large set

Tags: algorithm, search, indexing, computational-geometry, knn

I have large set of points in multidimensional space. And I'd like to find few neighbours (within the neighborhood) for any given point (require is to avoid scanning of all points).

I want to know if my solution is appropriate:

Pre processing:

1. Define set of **ortogonal axises**
2. Make a **projection** of each point on each axis
3. Each projection is associated with its distance from the start point of axis (key) and identifier of point (value). **Index projections** - put all of them into sorted set (e.g. tree set)

> ```
> dist = distance of projection to the start point of axis
> point_num = number of point 
> sorted_set.put( dist, point_num )
> ```

To find neighbours for any given point:

1. Find its projection on each axis
2. Using idexes - find nearest projections on each exis
3. To find actual neighbours - **intersect** of all results

> ```
> dx = radius of neighborhood (some constant) 
>
> dist_1 = distance of projection of given point to start point of axis_1 
> list_1 = sorted_set_1.get_sub_set( dist_1 - dx, dist_1 + dx )
>
> dist_2 = distance of projection of given point to start point of axis_2
> list_2 = sorted_set_2.get_sub_set( dist_2 - dx, dist_2 + dx ) 
>
> return intersection_of( list_1, list_2 )
> ```

Here is a simple example:

[image]

Intersecting `[2, 4, 1]` and `[4, 5]` produces answer `[4]`

Please, point me, if I have done any mistakes in my algorithm

Thanks

Comment: How does "2. Make a projection of each point on each axis" avoid a scan of all points like you require?

Comment: Preprocessing would be done only once (with complexity O(N*lg(N)) in case of red-black tree as underlying structure of index) - so it is not a problem for me. But finding of neighbours is very frequent operation, so I don't want to scan all points each time, when finding neighbours for each given point.

Comment: Have you looked into K-D trees? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

Comment: Yes, thanks. But I wonder, if my solution is appropriate (as it have the same complexity as K-D tree). Is there any cases, which can't be covered by my solution?

Comment: Basically your algorithm builds a set of sorted values for all axes. Given that you have n values and d dimensions, you will consume O(n*d) space for your lists, each of size n. Then you sort each list spending O(d*n log n) time. Total pre-processing is O(n*d) + O(d*n log n) = O(n*d) with a big constant.  Getting your k nearest neighbors in each list requires at least O(log n) time, for a total of O(d log n) as you are getting the neighbors of all the lists. And then performing list intersection will take at least O(k*d) time. I don't think this is very efficient.

Comment: In fact, number of dimensions (`d`) is limited (constant), and number of points (`N`) is very large, so `d << N`. Thats why, in my case: `O(n*d) + O(d*n log n) = O(n) + O(n*log(N)) = O(n*log(N))`. I expect, my algorithm, would be easy to scale horizontally (to be honest, I don't know if K-D trees are easily to scale).

Comment: Your task is usually solved using n dimensional quad trees (oct trees). There is a whole 1000 page book: Hannan Sammet: Foundations of multidimensional search structures

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given us instructions on how to build your actual neighbors set, in this case `[2, 4, 1]` and `[4, 5]`.  Why did you choose 3 elements from one index and 2 from another?

You also state that you'd like to find a few neighbors.  How many is a few or should it be an input to your function?  In the example you only find one, should the algorithm decide how many you want?

What happens in the case where all of the points are on a line on one of your axis?  Then one set is certain to contain all elements.

Comment: I have embed some pseudo-code into my question. For indexes, for example, red-black tree might be used - they allows to find keys within the neighborhood in O(lg(N)) time.